# Dll not found error while using monolibusb

Tags: c#, libusb-1.0

I am trying to do a bulk transfer using monolibusb, but whenever I try to run the code, I get the following error.

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'libusb-1.0.dll not found. If this is a 64bit operating system, ensure that the 64bit version of libusb-1.0.dll exists in the '\Windows\System32' directory.'

I haven't yet found a solution on the internet that has worked for me. Any help would be appreciated. 
I have already tried downloading and copying the dll files into System32 and SysWOW64 and still to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The dll referenced is not compatible to your operating system or its not found.

Download the zip from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusb/files/libusb-1.0/)

Extract the contents like below

> \MS32\dll\libusb-1.0.dll ---> C:\windows\SysWOW64\
>
> \MS64\dll\libusb-1.0.dll ---> C:\windows\System32\

In production system you can install the dll in **Global assembly Cache** . [Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac)

Comment: which version of windows you have?

Comment: Its not loading it into GAC either. Says installation failed.

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: can you try placing the **libusb-1.0.dll** in you bin directory?  Be sure to paste 32 bit or 64bit dll based on your project